# converting 2, 4, 6 into 1, 2, 3?

Tags: ruby

My flappy bird clone is almost super complete and I have just one error left. Since I added 2 pipes from both the sky and the ground, the score keeps adding 2 since there are 2 objects for pipes. What I want to do is to convert those 2 increments into 1. My idea is to divide them by 2 but I need to know the algorithm of it.

Here's the code that I tried...

```
    def add_score
        if @x == @window.width / 2
            $score += 1
            $score /= 2 if $score >= 2
        end
    end
```

score just stays at 1

EDIT:
NVM solved it using this:

```
def add_score       
    if @x == @window.width / 2
        $add += 1
        $score += $add / 2 
    end
end
```

Comment: if score=2 then the score will be score/2 = 1.
And score +=1 then score =2.
And score/2 = 1.
And so on, then stay 1

Comment: An sensible (i.e. the most correct) fix would be to not `add_score` for each pipe then, but for each pair of pipes. This might require restructuring some of your other code. A workable and easy fix would be to keep adding 2 points for each pair of pipes, but _display_ `@score / 2` to the user. Possibly rename the variable to `@double_score` in that case, so you don't confuse the you-from-two-months-in-the-future.

Comment: Quick fix: make _either_ the sky pipes _or_ the ground pipes (not both) increment the score. A more sustainable approach is to decouple the underlying game structure (an abstract obstacle at some x-position the player has to pass) from its visual representation (a sky pipe and a ground pipe).